# Xtext - run my grammar

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I have a grammar made in xtext for ALF language where i can launch an eclipse application from the plugin.xml and test my grammar.

I need to add a button "run" to execute my alf code.

How can I do it ?

Comment: can you give more context on what "run" means for a ALF file

Comment: I'm trying to create an alf IDE with xtext. When I run the plugin.xml as an eclipse application it opens a new instance of eclipse where I can create and test .alf files. I need to add a button run to interpret this files.

Comment: Is this specific for XText, or are you just asking "how to add a custom 'Run' option to an Eclipse plugin"? (And then parsing the content of the current file in the editor, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to add Things to Eclipse is Commands and Handlers.
you would add a handler that reads the model and then call your interpreter.
you can find here examples on how to add a handler for mydsl files here: https://dietrich-it.de/xtext/2011/10/15/xtext-calling-the-generator-from-a-context-menu.html (it calls the generator and not an interpreter though)

for the general run as command you need to implement a launch delegate (https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug_launch_adding.htm)

Comment: This adds a context-menu entry to the file type, not a Run command.

Comment: do you ask for the default run as command? therefore you have to implement a Launch Delegate https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug_launch_adding.htm